# Codeigniter helper not working

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new in codeigniter and i create a blog site and i use bootstrap css file and I put bootstrap.min.css file in my codeigniter file in a folder assets/css/bootstrap.min.css when i use hard code link then it is loading but when I use 'url' helper or  'html' helper then my css file not load.

base URL like this:-

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php base_url('/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css'); ?>">
```

[image]

and I load helper from auto load like this:-

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url');
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should add `echo` to get the value printed

Like this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url('/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css'); ?>">
                                                   ^  ^
```

Or you can use `<?=` instead of `<?php echo`

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?= base_url('/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css'); ?>">
```